# Bootstrap - how to make the textbox responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, textbox

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a Textbox with some text in it. How can I make It responsive, i.e. to adapt to the screen size as I resize the window ? With images it is "image-responsive" class, but how about Textbox ? Highly appreciate your help.

```
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="container-fluid bounceIn animated", style="height:500px;width: 700px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;position: relative; left: 350px;top: 16px; background-color: white ">

<p> My long text is here </p> 


</div>              
  </div>
```

Comment: put your text box in div class="col-md-* col-sm-* col-xs-*" the input box will resize according to the div also add class form-control to the input box

Answer (score 1):

It will never be responsive if you give it a fixed pixel-width as you currently do. Simply remove `width: 700px;` from your div style.

It's still likely that it won't look responsive if you don't remove or reduce the horizontal position shifting. I don't know what you're trying to do but you should get rid of `left: 350px;` or at least reduce a lot its value.

Lastly, you should place a `div.row` inside a `div.container` or `div.container-fluid`, not the other way around.